# Positive matrices are open

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

An linear application $A:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is positive when it is symmetric and besides that $\langle Ax,x\rangle\gt 0$ for every $x\neq 0$ in $\mathbb R^n$. I would like to prove the set of the positive linear applications is open in the set of symmetric applications.

I don't have any idea how to prove it.

How does this matrix look like? I think this question can be answered directly from that.

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: The matrix is symmetric, and also all its leading principal minors are positive. This means it is symmetric and all its eigenvalues are positive

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras This is a characterization of the positive definite matrix, not positive matrix.

Comment: What topology is being used?

Comment: Oh, sorry @Rob1.10 . I thought it was the same.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I think the usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator norm of a matrix $A$ is $\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$. The claim is that if $\|A - B\|$ is small, then $B$ is positive too. It suffices to prove that $\langle Bx,x \rangle > 0$ whenever $\|x\| = 1$.

Let $\alpha = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \langle Ax,x \rangle$. Since the unit sphere in $\mathbf R^n$ is compact we have $\alpha > 0$.

If $\|x\| = 1$ then
$$ \langle Ax , x \rangle - \langle Bx , x \rangle = \langle (A-B)x,x \rangle \le \|(A-B)x\| \|x\| \le \|A-B\|.$$ In particular, $\|x\| = 1$ implies
$$
\langle Bx , x \rangle \ge \alpha - \|A-B\|.$$
This is positive if $\|A-B\| < \alpha$.

Comment: Why $\langle (A-B)x,x \rangle \le \|(A-B)x\| \|x\|$?

Comment: By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Note that $\alpha=\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$.

Comment: @user161825 of course, stupid question.

Comment: @user161825 I'm sorry to ask again, but why $\|(A-B)x\| \|x\| \le \|A-B\|$?

Comment: In that context $\|x\| = 1$.

Comment: But you proved $\langle Bx,x\rangle \gt 0$ just for $\|x\|=1$

Comment: One last question why $\alpha$ exists? I mean why $\alpha$ is reached?

Comment: $\alpha$ happens to be smallest eigenvalue of $A$, so it is reached if you pick $x$ to be a normalized eigenvector corresponding to $\alpha$.

Comment: @user161825 Do you know where I can find this fact proved? I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Can you convince yourself that $\phi(x) = \langle Ax,x \rangle$ is continuous on the unit sphere? If so, it must attain a positive minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Is the following solution correct?

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of positive linear applications. For each $x$ st $|x|=1$ define $ f_x: \mathcal{A} \to  \mathbb{R} $ by $\langle Ax,x\rangle$.
$f_x$ is continuous and $(0,\infty)$ is open. So
$f_x^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is Open. So,
$$
 \mathcal{A}=\bigcup_{|x|=1} f_x^{-1}((0,\infty))
 $$ is Open.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A>0$. Then $A$ is invertible and $A\geq \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\cdot I$. It follows that
$$
A+B\geq \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\cdot I +B \geq(\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}-\|B\|)\cdot I>0
$$
whenever $\|B\|<\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$. This shows that (in the set of symmetric, real matrices) the ball around $A$ with radius $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ is contained in the set of positive matrices, namely let $C$ be a symmetric matrix with $\|A-C\|<\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$, then $C=A+(C-A)$, which allows us to use the result above, with $B=(C-A)$.

Notation: For a description of the notation I use, check out the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties) on positive definite matrices, where most of the properties I make use of are also mentioned.

Addendum: Why is A invertible, and how do we get the lower bound. Let $A>0$. Then $A$ is in particular self-adjoint, so the [Finite Dimensional Spectral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case) allows us to pick a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ such that, with respect to this basis,
$$
A=\mbox{diag }(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n),
$$
where $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\ldots\geq\lambda_n>0$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ in decreasing order. Now you can show that $\|A\|=\lambda_1$ and that $A$ is invertible, namely
$$
A^{-1}=\mbox{diag }(1/\lambda_1,\ldots,1/\lambda_n).
$$
In particular, you can show that
$$
\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq \lambda_n=1/(1/\lambda_n)=\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}
$$
for all $x$ with $\|x\|=1$, and that there is equality if $x=e_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, why this prove the question?

Comment: It proves that all symmetric matrices in the open ball of radius $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ around $A$ are positive.

Comment: What does $A\gt 0$ mean?

Comment: It means $\langle Ax,x\rangle>0$ for all $x$.

Comment: So $A\ge \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\cdot I$ means $\langle Ax,x\rangle\ge\langle (\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\cdot I)x,x\rangle$?

Comment: @Rob1.10 Yes, that is precisely what it means. I have added a passage on how to get the lower bound $A\geq \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}\cdot I$.