# The set of positive Linear transformations is open and convex.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We say a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is positive if:

- $\left\langle Tx,y\right\rangle = \left\langle x,Ty\right\rangle$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$
- if $x \not =0$ then $\left\langle Tx,x\right\rangle>0$.

Show that the set of positive linear transformation is convex and open set in the set of symmetric  linear transformation.

A linear transformation $S:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is symmetric  if:

- $\left\langle Sx,y\right\rangle = \left\langle x,Sy\right\rangle$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Let S the set of symmetric linear transformation and P the set of positive linear transformation.

P is convex:
let  $T_1, T_2 \in P $ and $t \in \left(0,1 \right) $ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \left\langle \left( (1-t)T_1+tT_2\right)x,y  \right\rangle&=& (1-t)\left\langle T_1x,y \right\rangle+t\left\langle T_1x,y \right\rangle  \\
 &=&(1-t)\left\langle x,T_1y \right\rangle+ t\left\langle x,T_2y \right\rangle\\
 &=& \left\langle x, \left( (1-t)T_1+tT_2\right)y  \right\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}

and

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \left\langle \left( (1-t)T_1+tT_2\right)x,x\right\rangle &=&(1-t)\left\langle T_1x,x \right\rangle+t\left\langle T_1x,x \right\rangle  \\
 &\geqslant& \min\left\lbrace\left\langle T_1x,x \right\rangle,\left\langle T_2x,x \right\rangle \right\rbrace > 0
\end{eqnarray*}

P is open set.

Let $e_1:\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \right) \times \mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $e_1(A,x)= (Ax,x)$, and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow R$ given by $g(x,y)=\left\langle x,y \right\rangle $, $e_1$ and $g$ are continuos, then $f=g \circ e_1$ is continuos.

My idea is that $f^{-1}\left[\left( 0, \infty\right)  \right] $ is open in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$ and $\pi_1: \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \right)\times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$ is an open map, then $\pi_1(f^{-1}\left[\left( 0, \infty\right)  \right])$ is open in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$.

But $\pi_1(f^{-1}\left[\left( 0, \infty\right)  \right])\not = P$

Anyone is has a idea to prove that P is open set?

Note: I can't use compact sets or Finite Dimensional Spectral Theorem, then this solution [Positive matrices are open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947231/positive-matrices-are-open) doesn't help me.

Comment: What's your definition of "open" in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: The set of linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: That's what $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ means. Then there's a standard topology on that set, with a number of equivalent ways to describe it.

Comment: The topology induced by the norm $\left\| A\right\| =sup\left\lbrace \left\| Ax\right\| \mid \left\| x\right\|=1 \right\rbrace$

Comment: You could use that the matrix is positive definite if and only if all its principal minors have positive determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is positive definite.  We first show
$$ c := \inf \{ \langle x, Tx \rangle : \|x\| = 1 \} > 0.$$
Suppose $c = 0$.  Then there exists a sequence $x_n$ with $\|x_n\| = 1$, such that $\langle x_n, T x_n \rangle \to 0$.  Let $x$ be an accumulation point for the sequence $(x_n)$.  Then $\|x\| = 1$, and $\langle x, Tx \rangle = 0$.  This is a contradiction.

So, if $\|S-T\| < \tfrac12 c$, and $x \ne 0$, then
$$ \langle x, S x \rangle = \langle x, T x \rangle + \langle x, (S-T) x \rangle \ge c \|x\|^2 - \|S-T\| \|x\|^2 > \tfrac12 c \|x\|^2 > 0,$$
that is, $S$ is positive definite.

Comment: I'm looking for a proof that doesn't use compactness

Comment: What tools are you allowed to use?

Comment: I can use the Euclidean norm, Taxicab norm and Maximum norm in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: What linear algebra tools are you allowed to use?

Comment: The problem is of Curso de Análisis Vol.2 - Elon L. Lima(Cap 1 Problem 10.10), I have analisys tools of this sections https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP7f3.png

Comment: I used accumulation points instead of compactness.  Does this work?

Comment: Yes, this work, 
thank you